# Testing association in repeated measures with zero in contingency table

Tags: r, repeated-measures, generalized-estimating-equations

I have a small dataset of repeated measures data (each participant (`id`) has up to two samples taken) and would like to determine if there is an association between a dichotomous predictor (`predictor`) and the dichotomous outcome (`outcome`) by running a logistic regression through GEE.

However, when examining the data I have the following contingency table:

```
       predictor
outcome  0  1
      0 16  0
      1 13  9
```

Thus my model fails to converge:

```
gee::gee(outcome ~ predictor, data = df, id = id, family = binomial, corstr = "exchangeable")

Error in gee(outcome ~ predictor, data = df, id = id, family = binomial,  : 
  Cgee: error: logistic model for probability has fitted value very close to 1.
estimates diverging; iteration terminated.
```

Since these data are correlated, I imagine implementing Fisher’s exact test isn't appropriate. Are there alternative statistical approaches to examine this relationship?

Example data are here:

```
df <- structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
                                           4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 
                                           12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 
                                           21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L), 
                                         levels = c("K6003", "K6008", "K6015", 
                                         "K6030", "K6075", "K6088", "K6106", "K6113", "K6129", "K6171", 
                                         "K6283", "K6308", "K6312", "K6334", "K6335", "K6342", "K6367", 
                                         "K6412", "K6421", "K6448", "K6462", "K6523", "K6551"), class = "factor"), 
                     outcome = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                         1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), 
                                       levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
                     predictor = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
                                      1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                      1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                      1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(5L, 
                                      6L, 12L, 13L, 21L, 40L, 41L, 74L, 75L, 84L, 108L, 111L, 112L, 
                                      119L, 120L, 152L, 153L, 236L, 237L, 258L, 259L, 262L, 263L, 287L, 
                                      288L, 289L, 296L, 323L, 324L, 356L, 366L, 375L, 376L, 384L, 440L, 
                                      441L, 468L, 469L))
```